# React module.css add part of class name dynamically

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I would like to add a part of a classname dynamicall with modules.css.

My classnames are arrow1, arrow2, arrow3, arrow4. So I would like to change the number at the end dynamically.

```
className={`${styles.box}` + ' styles.arrow' + id}
```

I tried it liek this and some other ways, but it never worked. How can I add the number (id)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently adding a **string** `"styles.arrow1"` which does not reference the styles object. Instead you can target your className like so

```js
className={`${styles.box} ` + styles["arrow" + id]}
```

Comment: Thank you!!
I knew the mistake, but I really couldn't correct it

Comment: If this is the correct answer you can accpeted it as the answer to help people who might have the same issue in the future @Kocher

Comment: sorry, forgot about that